# Receive AJAX response from controller function defined in included file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that submits an ajax call to the controller file below which has a function defined in another file "processes.php" [that I've included]. The challenge is receiving the json response; the browser expects to find it in the controller yet it's generated within the function. How can I retrieve the response from the function and make it readable from the controller [outside its functions] so that the response can be read by the browser?

> controller.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['postdata'] = $_POST;
    require "constants.php";
    $file = $_SESSION["Form"].".php";
    require $file;
    if( isset($_POST["Save"]) ){
        save_record($connection);
    }
```

> process.php

```
<?php
    $_POST = $_SESSION['postdata'];
    function save_record($connection){
        $errors = array();      // array to hold validation errors
        $data = array();        // array to pass back data
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["name"]);
        $strQuery = "INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES ('$name')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $strQuery); //or exit("Error in query execution attempt!");

        if($result){

            $data['success'] = true;
            $data['message'] = 'Success!';
        }
        else{
            $errors['errorinexecute'] = "Error in query execution attempt!";
        }
        mysqli_close($connection);
        unset($_SESSION["postdata"]);

        if ( ! empty($errors)) {

            // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
            $data['success'] = false;
            $data['errors']  = $errors;
        }
        else{
            $data['success'] = true;
            $data['errors']  = $errors;
        }
        // return all our data to an AJAX call
        echo json_encode($data);

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use:

```
if( isset($_POST["Save"]) ){
    save_record($connection);
}
```

when doing AJAX, so what I did is pass the button id into the JavaScript function like so:

```
onclick="saveInfo(this.id)"
```

The button id shows whether it's a "Delete", "Save", "Edit" request and so on and then from there the PHP file can read like this:

```
if( $buttonId == "Save" ){

save_record($connection);

}
```